# IQKeyboardManager not disabling

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

Trying to disable `IQKeyboardManager` for a particular ViewController or for the whole app, it's not working.

My AppDelegate code:

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:NO];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:NO];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] disableToolbarInViewControllerClass:[TCChatViewController class]];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] disableInViewControllerClass:[TCChatViewController class]];
```

Also trying to disable in `viewWillAppear:` :

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:NO];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:NO];
```

Comment: Could you please let know what you actually need and what is happening right now?

Comment: Im using IQKeyboardManager through app, but I need to disable it for particular VC, and I can change its settings. It looks like setting is changing, but Manager doesn't using them.

Comment: I can see you're doing right, but don't know why you're getting issues. Please raise an issue on the repo issue tracker and upload sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in 'Class implemented in both', because library was included to main app and framework. So I guess I was setting library preferences to one copy, but library was reading preferences from another copy and mine was ignored.

Comment: i dont understand please elaborate it

Comment: @jaskiratjd `IQKeyboardManager` pod was linked against main app and my framework, so library preferences was overwritten i guess. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 9):

Disable IQKeyboard Manager In Objective C

> If you want to disable **IQKeyboardManager** in particular controller
>   of your project. Then add this line in your viewController Class.

```
 #import "IQKeyboardManager.h"
```

Now In View Controller **viewDidLoad** Methods, add the below function

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:false];
```

Now when you leave the controller, so that your **IQKeyboardManager** will enable when you leave that viewController**.

```
In **viewWillDisappear** Method:-

[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:true];
```

> Disable IQKeyboard Manager In Swift 3.0

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = false
}

 //MARK:- viewWillDisappear
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = true
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
}
```

> Disable IQKeyboard Manager In Swift 4.2

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
}

 //MARK:- viewWillDisappear
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
}
```

Comment: That's wrong. `setEnableAutoToolbar` enables/disables the `IQKeyboardManager`'s  auto toolbar, not the `IQKeyboardManager` as a whole.

Comment: @mrvincenzo i just mention that it will disable IQKeyboardManager's auto toolbar from that class where did i mention that it will remove the whole IQKeyboardManager. Tell me i will check and i mention that If you want to disable IQKeyboardManager in particular controller of your project. First understand the answer then say someone you are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

**Try This**

Just Put below line in Your ViewController viewDidLoad.

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:false];
```

Put Below line in Your ViewController viewWillDisappear;

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:true];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:NO];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:NO];
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldResignOnTouchOutside:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 this is what worked for me in particular vc:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(MyController.self)
IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledToolbarClasses = [MyController.self]
```