# disable nativescript IQKeyboardManager plugin for a view

Tags: nativescript

How do you disable `nativescript-IQKeyboardManager` plugin for a specific view?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003246/iqkeyboardmanager-not-disabling) but it seems to be done not through this plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `enable` property on `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager` like this, for instance in a 'loaded' event or the constructor of your component:

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = false;
```

Comment: I also added `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false;` because i had the "done" button displayed in it's own bar.
Thank you!